# At what point would an elementary generalization of Bertrand's Postulate be interesting?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, elementary-proofs

I know that in 1952 [Jitsuro Nagura](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-28/issue-4/On-the-interval-containing-at-least-one-prime-number/10.3792/pja/1195570997.full) was able to show that there is always a prime between $k$ and $\frac{6k}{5}$ for $k > 24$.

At what point would an improvement on Nagura's result be interesting?  If an approach could show for example that for any $k$, there is a specific value $X$ which could be calculated such that for all $x \ge X$, there is a prime between $kx$ and $(k+1)x$, would this be interesting?

Or, does the Prime Number Theorem provide us enough insight that short of a proof of Legendre's Conjecture, elementary results are not very interesting at this time?

Comment: From the Erdos-Selberg argument, it is not too difficult to see (basically by iterating the Selberg symmetry formula) that if one can get $\gg_k x/\log x$ primes between $kx$ and $(k+1)x$ for all $k$ and all sufficiently large $x$, then the prime number theorem follows from elementary means (of course, this is a somewhat vacuous statement since the entire Erdos-Selberg proof of PNT is already considered elementary, but the derivation here is simpler than that of full Erdos-Selberg).  

Comment: From the explicit formula linking primes and zeroes, the above assertion for a given $k$ is morally equivalent to the absence of a zero on the line $\{ Re(s)=1 \}$ of imaginary part $O(k)$.  I vaguely recall reading some discussion in which this equivalence could be made more precise, in that such a zero-free region could be converted to an elementary Ramanujan-style result (somewhat analogously to how the non-vanishing of $L(1,\chi)$ for all $\chi$ of period $q$ can be converted to an elementary proof of Dirichlet's theorem mod $q$) but I don't remember the details.

Comment: Ah, I found the reference now, in this survey of Diamond: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183549769 .  In section 9 he discusses how, for each k, there is an elementary proof of Chebyshev type of a prime between $kx$ and $(k+1)x$ for large enough x.  Unfortunately, the proof that the elementary proof exists (!) itself depends on the PNT!

Comment: Thanks very much for the reference!  I look forward to checking it out.

Comment: I found in my lecture notes a reference to a paper by N.Costa Pereira
that proves $|\psi(x)/x - 1| < 1/2976$ for $x > 10^{11}$:
"Elementary estimates for the Chebyshev function psi(x) and the 
Möbius function M(x)", *Acta Arithmetica* **52** (1989), 307-337.

Comment: Despite being "elementary", I have eschewed such arguments in favor for proofs / write-ups that are easier to read. I am dissatisfied that I cannot map the complex analysis to elementary strategies. We are forced to accept ex nihilo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Current results are able to yield such results. Depending on how generous one is regarding what $X$ is. If it is just the optimal value can be calculated *exactly* this will work for many more $k$ and if one is happy with an explicit bound for all $k$.

For example Dusart showed that 
$$  
\frac{x}{\log x - 1} \le \pi(x) \le \frac{x}{\log x - 1.1} 
$$
for $x\ge 60184$.
Now for some $k$, write $y=kx$. 
Then, if the upper bound for $kx=y$ is smaller than the lower bound for $(k+1)x = (1+1/k)y$, that is
$$
\frac{y}{\log y - 1.1} \lt  \frac{y(1+ 1/k)}{\log( y  (1+1/k) )- 1}
$$
one has a prime between $kx$ and $(k+1)x$, since then $\pi(kx) \lt \pi((k+1)x)$.

One can check that this inequality holds for (up to potential error in my calculation)
$$
y \ge 10 e^{0.1 k}.
$$

So, for $x \ge \max \lbrace 10 e^{0.1 k}/k , 60184/k \rbrace $ one always has a prime between $kx$ and $(k+1)x$.

While this grows exponential in $k$, the growth is such that it is well feasible to check 'everything' up to the bound to get an optimal $X$ for not too large $k$. And, one always has an explict value.

This proof is of course not elementary (the non-elementariness being hidden in Dusart's result) and is an application of the PNT in some sense. But what this is meant to show is that for a result around this to be interesting it seems necessary either to be better (and one could still optimize this here) than this *or* the proof would have to be interesting (or both). [What an interesting proof is is of course a bit subjective.]

Comment: Just to be clear regarding the 'up to error': this will work with *some* explicit value, it just could be a different one if I made an error.

Comment: @quid: I edited the first inequality, since the left-hand side was larger than the right-hand side. -- Please check! 

Comment: @Stefan Kohl: Thank you! Yes this was written in the wrong order. Also, the second is wrong (as I first copied and then modified). I will chanhe the later one now. 

Comment: As a check on your equations I set k=100 x=2478 and should therefore expect one prime between 2478 and 2478 + 2478/100 = 2502.78. (for k=100, x must be greater than 2202.65 as detailed by your equations - this condition is met for x=2478). But there are no primes between 2478 and 2502.78. (Though 2503 is prime) Is the domain of x for your answer the positive integers? Then everything checks out. Or as you warned 'up to error'? Appreciate your answer and went through this numerical check to see when a 1% addition to any x>2203 guarantees a prime in what seems to me to be a very short interval.

Comment: Thank you for the interest in my answer. Note the prime is between $kx$ and $(k+1)x$. So in this case $247800$ and $247800 + 2478$, and  $247800+ 11$ is prime.

Answer (score 5):

I think that it would be interesting if it has an effective (and not too huge) value of $X$.

Comment: Thanks very much.  That helps.  I am reviewing Ramanujan's proof of Bertrand's Postulate and I'm wondering if his approach can be applied to an arbitrary value of $k$.  I'm still getting up to speed so my thoughts are very preliminary.

Answer (score 2):

Once again, being new here I tried to comment your answer, but obviously don't have 50 points yet.

Here is the original text of my comment with my mistake on value of x

"As a check on your equations I set k=100 x=2478 and should therefore expect one prime between 2478 and 2478 + 2478/100 = 2502.78.(for k=100, x must be greater than 2202.65 as detailed by your equations - this condition is met for x=2478).But there are no primes between 2478 and 2502.78. (Though 2503 is prime) Is the domain of x for your answer the positive integers? Then everything checks out okay. Or as you warned 'up to error'?"

**Assigning x=24.78 is the correct value.**

@quid: Note the prime is between kx and (k+1)x, so with my corrected value of x there should be a prime between 2478 < (some prime) < 2502.78, but the next prime is 2503.

@stefan kohl: understood and my calculation and answer/comment also gave x > 2202.65. My mistake was not putting the correct value for x

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/62692)

Comment: Dear fellow MO users: the author of this post doesn't have the rep to make comments in response to comments under someone else's post, but would like to do so. I propose that we keep this "answer" for a while and then convert the kit and caboodle over to comments once a bit of rep has accrued. I expect this user can make further useful comments and contributions, but his/her hands are tied at the moment.

Comment: @ToddTrimble At least marh_g followed the advice given in [this meta answer](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/639/70808). And imho, this "answer" is interesting enough not to be deleted immediately.

Comment: @Todd, can't you, as a mod, convert an answer to comments, regardless of how many points the person has?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ordinarily I do just that, and in fact I did that before with a very similar post (which OP appreciated); see below the accepted answer. But then when people began making comments on his comment and OP was unable to respond, he/she flagged to explain so. In view of this and Sebastian's comment, I'm going to keep this answer, at least temporarily.

Comment: @StefanKohl yes it does in the sense that you can vastly improve the k to 6k/5 bound  to finding a prime between k and 101k/100. That is, from a 1.2 factor to 1.01.