# Approximating integers with prime quotients

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is this statement true for all positive integers $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

> > For all $\varepsilon >0$ there are prime numbers $p,q$ such that $|\frac{p}{q} - n| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Yes, and it is even true that for every $\alpha \in \mathbf R$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbf R^+$ there exist (rational) primes $p, q \in \mathbf Z$ such that $|\alpha - p/q| < \varepsilon$; see, e.g., at the bottom of p. 165 in W. Sierpiński, *Elementary Theory of Numbers*, Amsterdam: North-Holland Mathematical Library **31**, North-Holland, 1988 (2nd edition).

Comment: Thanks Salvo! I guess I should delete this question... Or you can put your comment as an answer ... as you wish!

Comment: Some posts on Math.SE:
[Rationals of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are primes in $[a,b]$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/),
[The set of rational numbers of the form p/p', where p and p' are prime, is dense in $[0, \infty)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19916)
and [Are fractions with prime numerator and denominator dense?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013414/are-fractions-with-prime-numerator-and-denominator-dense).
Related MO post: [Using Quotient of Prime Numbers to Approximation Reals](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117191).

Comment: You can also read [Quotients of Primes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324814?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by David Hobby and D. M. Silberger.

Comment: @Watson Hobby and Silberger's paper is cited in my answer below (item 3 in the list there).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an addendum to my comment above, but too long for another comment. I think it's safe to say that the following (more general) result: "For every  $\alpha \in \mathbf R$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbf R^+$ there exist (rational) primes $p,q \in \bf Z$ such that $|\alpha−p/q|<\varepsilon$" is well-known, and here is a (partial) list of references where it is mentioned or proved (to try to convince you that yes, it is *really* well-known):

1. P. 165 in: W. Sierpiński, *Elementary Theory of Numbers*, North-Holland Mathematical Library **31**, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1988 (2nd edition).
2. Theorem 4 in: P. Ribenboim, *The Book of Prime Number Records*, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1989 (2nd edition).
3. Theorem 4 in: D. Hobby and D. M. Silberger, *Quotients of primes*, Amer. Math. Monthly **100** (1993), No. 1, 50–52 ([click](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324814?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)).
4. Corollary 2 in:  P. Starni, *Answers to two questions concerning quotients of primes*, Amer. Math. Monthly **102** (1995), No. 4, 347–349 ([click](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2974957?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)).
5. Exercise 4.19 in: B. Fine and G. Rosenberger, *Number Theory: An Introduction via the Distribution of Primes*, Birkhäuser, Boston, 2007.
6. Exercise 218 in: J.-M. De Koninck and A. Mercier, *1001 Problems in Classical Number Theory*, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2007.
7. Exercise 7, p. 107 in: P. Pollack, *Not Always Buried Deep:  A Second Course in Elementary Number Theory*, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2009.
8. Corollary 5 in: S. R. Garcia, V. Selhorst-Jones, D. E. Poore, and N. Simon, *Quotient sets and Diophantine equations*, Amer. Math. Monthly **118** (2011), No. 8, 704–711 ([click](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.08.704)).

For the record: I compiled this list at some point, based on information drawn from an arXiv preprint (unfortunately, I didn't take note of either a link, the author(s), or the title of the preprint, so I don't know how to find it again), as the question popped up in relation to a certain property of densities.

Comment: Possibly  [Stephan Ramon Garcia, *Quotients of Gaussian primes*, 2013](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.3158), later appearing in [Amer. Math. Monthly](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.09.851)

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 6):

It is known that there exists a prime between $n$ and $n+n^{\epsilon}$ for $n$ large enough, where the best known $\epsilon$ is 0.525. Therefore, given a large enough prime $q$, choose a prime $p$ between $q\alpha$ and $q\alpha+(q\alpha)^{\epsilon}$ to get 
$$|\alpha-p/q|<Cq^{\epsilon-1},$$
where $C$ depends only on $\alpha$. Assuming the Reimann Hypothesis, this bound can be improved to 
$$|\alpha-p/q|<Cq^{-1/2}\log q,$$
for infinitely many pairs of primes $(p,q)$. With recent results on prime gaps, this bound is extremely better when $\alpha=1$. One can then ask this question:

${\bf Question:}$ Let $\alpha$ be a positive real number. Does there always exist infinitely many pairs of primes $(p,q)$ such that
$$|\alpha-p/q|<C/q,$$
where $C$ is a universal constant?

Comment: The best known $\epsilon$ is $0.525$, see Baker-Harman-Pintz: The difference between consecutive primes, II, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 83 (2001) 532-562.