# Are the Farey numbers $\{ \frac{a}{b} : a < b, \gcd(a,b) = 1\}$ uniform in $[0,1]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

I did some numerical experiments about $\{ \frac{a}{b}: a,b \in A, \;a < \, b\}$ for various integer sets $A$.  Does anyone recognize these densities?

Here is $A = \{ p: \text{prime}\}$

[image]

Here is $A = \mathbb{Z}$

[image]

Here is if $\{ (a,b): a < 2 \, b, \; \gcd(a,b) = 1  \}$.  Does this uniform distribution surprise everybody?

[image]

---

Literature on each of these could be interesting.  I know there is discussion about the primes case being dense already:

- [Using Quotient of Prime Numbers to Approximation Reals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117191/using-quotient-of-prime-numbers-to-approximation-reals)

By default I can look for the Weyl Equidistribution Theorem.  We are told to evaluate sums:

$$ c_N(m) =  \sum_{0 < a < b < N} e^{2\pi i m \frac{a}{b}}  $$

These are the [sums of Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum), $c_q(n)$.  This paper of [Huxley](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa18/aa18130.pdf) states in the affirmative, and - in usual style - the result is so obvious he does not prove it.

In another place Huxley works it out.  He shows (unconditionally) just reasoning about fractions:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N e^{ 2\pi i \, m \frac{a}{b}} \ll d(m) \sqrt{N} $$
and this is [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence).  The other lemma I like is: Let $0 < x_n < 1$ be the [Farey fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) between $0$ and $1$:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N e(m x_n) = \sum_{d|m} d \left[ M( \tfrac{Q}{d}) \right] $$

where $M(x) = \sum_{m \leq x} \mu(m)$.  No effort was taken to optimize exponent.  This is already equivalent to $M(x) = o(x)$.

This is taken from Chapter **1** Huxley's book [Area, Lattice Points, and Exponential Sums](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198534663)

Comment: I think it's related to Farey sequences, from which one can get a criterion for the truth of RH.

Comment: [**Quotients of Primes**](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324814) David Hobby and D. M. Silberger

Comment: I have no idea what the graphs are meant to be. I don't even know what the axes are. But I know there's much discussion of the equidistribution of Farey sequences in the Kuipers & Niederreiter book.

Comment: There is some work by Boca, Cobeli, and Zaharescu that I think is quite closely related to your question. (see also the Hall distribution).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I googled *Hall distribution* and found this paper by Jayadev Athreya on the Gaps of Farey Fractions: arXiv:1210.0816 [Gap distributions and homogeneous dynamics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0816)

Comment: It is strange that  numerical experiments are done for $a<b$ but density function is supported on $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equidistribution in the last graph is equivalent to the prime number theorem, the optimal speed of equidistribution is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis. The way you get there is by taking Fourier transform of the empirical measure, and when the smoke clears, the decay of coefficients is equivalent to the fact that $\sum_{n<x} \mu(n) = o(x).$

**EDIT** A nice exposition can be found in this [University of Edinburgh senior project.](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/fareyproject.pdf)

Comment: Are you sure? It looks to me like the simpler fact that $\sum_{n<x} \mu(n)=o(x^2)$.

Comment: @WillSawin Did you note that $Q \asymp \sqrt{N}$ ?  I have that $\sum_{n<x} \mu(n)=O(x)$ which is somewhat less than the PNT.

Comment: @johnmangual The equidistribution follows from $\sum_{d|m} d M(Q/d) = o(N)$, which follows from $M(x) = o(x^2)$, because then $M(Q/d)=o(Q^2/d^2)=o(Q^2)=o(N)$. We can assume $m=O(1)$ so $d=O(1)$ and the sum is finite.

Comment: @WillSawin The book uses $\sum_{n < x}\mu(n) \leq  x$ which even I can verify.  Unfortunately, this is definitely **not** the PNT.  Even if I use $\zeta(1+it) \neq 0$ I still need the Wiener-Ikehara (or something) to prove $\sum_{n < x} \mu(n) = o(x)$.   At least, if I find some way to get better than $N^{1/2}$ on these Weyl averages, it's equivalent to PNT.

Comment: @johnmangual Exactly. I am saying that the equidistribution statement follows from the simpler bound $\sum_{n <x} \mu(n) \leq x$ and is thus not equivalent to the PNT.

Comment: @johnmangual Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @WillSawin I am very confused. $|\mu(n)| \leq 1,$ are you being sarcastic about the "simpler fact"?

Comment: Huxley's book on Areas and Lattice Points.  That's just the first book I found.  He shows Farey Fractions are equidistributed in $\mathbb{R}$ (they had better be!) and with error about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ and if you do better than that one should get PNT and if one gets  $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{N}}$ that might be RH.

Comment: @johnmangual Ah, OK, thanks! I was not actually aware of any reference...

Comment: @johnmangual see also the reference in the edit...

Comment: @IgorRivin I am not being sarcastic, I'm just trying to make a very slight correction but not communicating very clearly. I think your first statement is wrong because the Prime Number Theorem does not follow quickly from the equidistribution statement. The bound that the equidistribution statement is equivalent to is $\sum_{n < x} \mu(n)= o(x^2)$, which is trivial because, as you note, $|\mu(n)| \leq 1$. I agree that optimal equidistribution is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis.